# VBA code to check if there is any deletion of row

Tags: excel, vba

I want to do something if any row is deleted in excel. to check whether any row is being deleted.

I have written this - but it doesn't seems to be working. Please help.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)    
If Selection.EntireRow.Delete Then  "my condition"
End sub
```